# Issue on creating an application for facebook

Tags: facebook, ssl, https, hosting, web-hosting

Currently i am creating an sample facebook application. The problem is its asking for my application url in two types. **Canvas url and Secure canvas url** i had hosted my application on this link [Fb app url](http://praveen.comyr.com/fb/#slide1) but the hosting is not providing me ssl i.e. the link with **https** Because of this problem i am unable to include the **Secure canvas url**
How can i overcome this issue. How can i solve this. Is there any way to submit the facebook application without secure canvas url or is there any free webhosting site which also provides ssl (https). Please suggest me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try heroku . Facebook provides you that option while you are registering your app.

Answer (score 2):

no you have to get the ssl certificate to secure url

check this [What is SSL and what are Certificates?](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/SSL-Certificates-HOWTO/x64.html) and [Https connection without SSL certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865039/https-connection-without-ssl-certificate)

this is [Free SSL Certificate :by Comodo](http://www.instantssl.com/ssl-certificate-products/free-ssl-certificate.html) for 90 days but never tried by me