# how verify if data are encrypt when use git transfert?

Tags: git, encryption, https, gitlab

I have install my own gitlab on my server. I want to encrypt data on network during transfert (clone, push, pull...).

Datas are encrypt by default by Git protocol? Or need to enable https?

How verify if data on network are encrypt?

thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git itself doesn't encrypt anything during transport, that's up to the transport protocol.

Plaintext:

- file://
- git://
- http://

Encrypted:

- https://
- ssh://

Comment: Ok, it's like I think. So I have active HTTPS in my gitlab, but certificate is needle to be sure that datas are encrypt?

Comment: I believe you'll need _some_ kind of certificate for HTTPS to work at all, but a simple self-signed certificate is enough for encryption. However, you should obtain a proper CA-signed certificate so that clients can verify that they're actually connecting to you rather than someone else. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865039/https-connection-possible-without-a-valid-ssl-certificate.

Comment: yes I create my own crt CA, it's works. But you said ssh protocol is encrypted, it's only for authentification/connexion, not for data on network no?

Comment: SSH encrypts the data in transit too.